# Does OSMnx/NetworkX provide a function that calculates a rout from start_node to end_node containing a set of predefined nodes (or edges)?

Tags: python, networkx, geopandas, osmnx

I am working on a simulation program of public transportation. The dataset contains coordinates of the start, end, and intermediate stops of each public transporation vehicle.

For example, let's take a bus with:

`start = (lat_start, lng_start)`

`end = (lat_end, lng_end)`

`stops = [(lat1, lng1),(lat2, lng2),(lat3, lng3)]`

I am using OSMnx/NetworkX to retrieve the complete route of the bus. OSMnx provides the built-in functionality that gets the nearest node or edge based on a (lat,long) point, which enables me to retrieve the nearest node/edge for each start, end and intermediate stop of the bus. However, I am wondering if NetworkX provides a function similar to nx.shortest_path(G, origin, destination, ***stops***)?

I have tried:

- to generate all paths between `start` and `end` and filter on the paths containing the subset `stops`. Besides the fact that this is computationally expensive it is not very effective since public transportation routes contain lots of detours and are far from 'the shortest path'.
- to split the process in parts such that:

`total_route = nx.shortest_path(G, start, stop1) + nx.shortest_path(G, stop1, stop2) + ... nx.shortest_path(G, stop 3, end)`
As a result, this kind of works, but is not very robust. Meaning that errors on sub_route level cause delays and inefficiencies.

In short, I am looking for a sound way to get a route (not necessarily the shortest) from start to end under the condition that the route contains a set of stops (nodes or edges).

Comment: Is this relevant https://docs.ocean.dwavesys.com/projects/dwave-networkx/en/latest/reference/algorithms/tsp.html#

Comment: Could you explain a bit how you would use the TSP to get the complete networkx route containing all the edges? How I understand the networkx.tsp.traveling_salesperson_qubo is that it returns the order of nodes. To clarify, I am interested in the entire networkx route of which the stops are only a subset.